# Colored stones on a chess board puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, combinatorics

We have a chess board of size n x n and there is exactly one stone on every square. We have green, blue and red stones. We must not have a row or a column full of stones of the same colour. We can omit using one of the colors. How many combinations of placing the stones are there?

Comment: Can we omit using two of the colors?

Comment: @EngineerToast, that would have n rows and columns of all the same color. I'm sure you were being sarcastic though.

Comment: @dperry I suppose that means a 1x1 grid is disallowed.

Comment: Are we to count all permutations or disregard rotations and reflections?

Comment: @EngineerToast count all of them - imagine you put a chess board in front of you and you are putting the stones on it.

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Comment: I think inclusion-exclusion looks like a very good way to about it. Looks like some work, but not hard work at all. Might give it some time later.

Comment: This looks like a textbook combinatorics problem, and I see no reason for there to be a clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the inclusion-exclusion principle, but it gets a little bit ugly because of the intersecting cases.

*Step 1:* There are $3^{n^2}$ ways of putting the coins down altogether.

---

*Step 2:* From that we need to **subtract** the ways of putting coins down that have at least one row or one column that are the same colour:
\begin{equation} 2\times\dbinom{8}{1}\times3^1\times(3^{n(n-1)}) \end{equation}
There's 16 rows and columns, which can each be 3 colours, and then a board of $n(n-1)$ left over.

---

*Step 3:* To that we need to **add** all the ways of putting coins down that have at least two rows or columns that are the same colour.

*Step 3.1:*  Two rows or two columns:
\begin{equation}2\times\dbinom{8}{2}\times3^2\times(3^{n(n-2)})\end{equation}

*Step 3.2:*  One row and one column (note they have to be the same colour):
\begin{equation}8^2\times3\times(3^{(n-1)(n-1)})\end{equation}

---

*Step 4:* To this we need to **subtract** all the ways of putting coins down that have at least three rows or columns that are the same colour.

*Step 4.1:*  Three rows or three columns:
\begin{equation}2\times\dbinom{8}{3}\times3^3\times(3^{n(n-3)})\end{equation}

*Step 4.2:*  One row and two columns or vice versa (note they have to be the same colour):
\begin{equation}2\times\dbinom{8}{2}\times\dbinom{8}{1}\times3\times(3^{(n-1)(n-2)})\end{equation}

---

Things carry on in this way for quite some time...

The tricksy thing is that the cases where there are a mixture of rows and columns of one colour, you immediately know that all the single colours rows and column are the same colour.  This gives (thanks @Mike Earnest for writing this out):

\begin{equation} 3^{n^2}-2\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i\binom{n}i3^{n(n-i)+i}+\sum_{i,j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j}\binom{n}i\binom{n}{j}3^{(n-i)(n-j)+1} \end{equation}

where the first term is from step 1, the second term represents the cases where there are $i$ rows or $i$ columns, and the third term represents the cases where there are a mixture of at least 1 row and at least 1 column.

Comment: You can the entire process as $3^{n^2}-2\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i\binom{n}i3^{n(n-i)+i}+\sum_{i,j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j}\binom{n}i\binom{n}{j}3^{(n-i)(n-j)+1}$.

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated my answer to include it.

Answer (score -1):

$2(3)^{2n-2}$

I am assuming that n must be at least 2, otherwise the board would have a row or column of all the same color.

Comment: Why would this be the answer?